# Reading statusbar from another application

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read the text from another application's statusbar that contains multiple panels. How would I go about that. I have tried to allocate memory in the other application and read that buffer based on this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5570/Stealing-Program-s-Memory

My current code is:

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(grxstatusbar, &statusbarpid);
statusbarprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, statusbarpid);

char* _buffer = nullptr;
char buffer[20];

_buffer = (char*)VirtualAllocEx(statusbarprocess, NULL, 20, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(statusbarprocess, _buffer, &buffer, 20, NULL);

SendMessage(grxstatusbar, SB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)_buffer);
ReadProcessMemory(statusbarprocess, _buffer, buffer, 20, NULL);
VirtualFreeEx(statusbarprocess, _buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

However, buffer is always just gibberish. What would be the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: I see the usual SO plague of not checking the result returned by API calls is alive and well:(

Comment: I didn't include checks in the question for brevity's sake.

Comment: Oh, OK, so all the calls succeed, then?

Comment: Forgive us for not believing you. Show a [mcve] and we might have more faith.

Comment: The call to `WriteProcessMemory` is unnecessary (I know you've just copied it from the other example, but it's not needed here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT *****

That won't work if target window is UNICODE. You can use `SB_GETTEXTLENGTH` to find the text length. Using the UNICODE version:

```
int char_count;
char_count = SendMessageW(hwndTarget, SB_GETTEXTLENGTH, 1, 0);
if (char_count <= 0)
    return 0;
char_count = LOWORD(char_count) + 1;

int datalen = LOWORD(char_count);
datalen *= sizeof(wchar_t);

void* data = VirtualAllocEx(hprocess, NULL, datalen, 
    MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

SendMessageW(hwndTarget, SB_GETTEXT, 1, (LPARAM)data);
wchar_t *buf = new wchar_t[char_count];
if (ReadProcessMemory(hprocess, data, buf, datalen, 0))
    std::wcout << "buf: " << buf << "\n";
delete[]buf;

VirtualFreeEx(hprocess, data, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hprocess);
```

Comment: Why are you allocating a `wchar_t` buffer instead of a `char` buffer when `IsWindowUnicode()` is false? And you are leaking both allocated buffers. And you should be using `SendMessageA()` for an Ansi window, not `SendMessageW()`.

Comment: You should be using `SendMessageA()` for `SB_GETTEXTLENGTH` as well.

Comment: It's irrelevant whether the target window is Unicode or not, surely. The system translates. Your memset calls are pointless and wrong, they pass the wrong length. But why would you zeroise memory that you are about to write to?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, I fixed the `memset` calls, however the memset calls are necessary and it doesn't work without checking `IsWindowUnicode`. Or do you mean I should use the Unicode-only version? (the OP was using ANSI-only version which is probably why it fails)

Comment: Actually, that was completely wrong before because `IsWindowUnicode` always returns true for status bar control, even if main window is ANSI (created through `RegisterClass`) - I changed it to Unicode-only version.